# Minchas Chinuch - Kuntres Bnei Noach ,is it available or lost?

Tags: jewish-books, mitzvah

This shabbos I came across a reference to a Kuntres bnei Noach in  the Minchas Chinuch Parshas Mishpatim on the mitzvah of Dini geneiva. Has anyone seen this kuntres anywhere ,is it available, is it lost,or maybe he didnt even get around to it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems from [this discussion](https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=2763) that this was an unpublished manuscript that unfortunately got lost or destroyed, and that in any case much of the original כתבי יד of the בעל מנחת חינוך is not available today.

Comment: What a shame :(